# Can I PIVOT this table?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table:

```
    ID   Name
    --   -----
    1    aaa
    2    bbb
    2    ccc
    2    ddd
    3    eee
    3    fff
    4    ggg
    5    hhh
```

I need to pivot this table so that the resulting table looks like this:

```
    ID   Name1  Name2  Name3  Name4  Name5  Name6
    --   -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
    1    aaa    NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
    2    bbb    ccc    ddd    NULL   NULL   NULL
    3    eee    fff    NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
    4    ggg    NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
    5    hhh    NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL
```

I have to use this on tables generated by XML Source in SSIS.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table is called Test:

```
select ID, [1] Name1, [2] Name2, [3] Name3, [4] Name4, [5] Name5, [6] Name6
from
(
    select id, name, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by id) as RowNum from Test
) AS A
PIVOT
(
    min(name)
    for RowNum in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])
) as PivotTable;
```

Comment: I tried replacing that `[1], [2]...` with `Name1, Name2...` after `for RowNum in...` but it didn't worked & throws datatype conversion error, any comment why it's not working?

Comment: Not sure, this is a very old answer so I can't remember anything about it and haven't done this kind of thing in SQL for a long time. Doesn't it work with the literal [1], [2]... in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SSIS, there're pivot and unpivot data flow elements you can use in your data flow task.